# Sprite images for object detection

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Let's say that I want to detect a character on a background image. The character can be tilted/moved in a number of ways, which will slightly change how we see him. Luckily, I have the sprite sheet for all of his possible positions. Is there a way to train tensorflow to detect objects/characters based on sprite sheets?

Comment: You can try augmenting your image data to the position mentioned in the sprite sheets. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).

Answer (score 0):

You can take different approaches:

1) I would first try out [Template Matching](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html). You slide your sprite over the image, and see if it matches the images. You do the same for the tilts, you tilt the sprite image, and slide the tilted sprite over the image. You do this for let's say every tenth of a degree, and take the best matching template.

2) If that's too computationally intensive, I would still use template matching, but only to gather data for a machine learning model. You can do template matching, then record the best match for a frame and the bounding boxes for that best match, and you can then use that to train an object detection network. There's more state-of-the-art stuff than this, but for ease-of-use I would [Yolov3](https://github.com/zzh8829/yolov3-tf2). it also has a `tiny` version, which is less accurate but way faster.